# Dealing with pages with many script files

Tags: javascript, performance

Our project contains many pages which has up to 20 tabs, each works with different scripts. All the script files are referenced in `<head>` and loads on the first page load. Now we have performance issue because there are too many scripts on the page loads on opening it (about 2k lines of JavaScript per tab). The matter is in much cases user needs to work with 2-3 tabs and as a result more than 60% of code becomes not used. So we need any scripts lazy-loading solution to ease the pages. As HTML for every tab is loaded on demand we can put `<script>` references in every tab that will provide a good working solution. But I'm prety sure including references not in `<head>` is a bad style.
So I wonder, is there any another solution? How such problems are solved in big projects like us? Any advice will be helpfull.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: yeah if you don't have your scripts referenced in the `<head>` tag then you will lose caching (I think!), which is generally going to interfere with performance. The main concern here though is, do you really need a separate javascript file for each tab? do they each have different functionality? Have you tried running a minimizer on your javascript files to see how small you can get them?

Comment: Correction: Don't need to be in head to be cached, just need to be used in `<script>` tag with `src` attribute. If it works for you to but references in the body, then do it

Comment: logic is really different for tabs and there is no way to merge in in single file because scripts are used in different areas. minimizing helps but not enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has a great function for this sollution:

```
$.getScript("my_lovely_script.js", function(){


   alert("Script loaded and executed.");
   // here you can use anything you defined in the loaded script

});
```

This is by default not cached. I looked for a solution on the jQuery website it stated  this solution for a cached script include.

```
jQuery.cachedScript = function(url, options) {

  // allow user to set any option except for dataType, cache, and url
  options = $.extend(options || {}, {
    dataType: "script",   //Note this
    cache: true,          //Enable caching
    url: url
  });

  // Use $.ajax() since it is more flexible than $.getScript
  // Return the jqXHR object so we can chain callbacks
  return jQuery.ajax(options);
};

// Usage
$.cachedScript("URL HERE").done(function(script, textStatus) {
  console.log( textStatus );
});
```

Comment: what about caching in browser? do the scripts loaded with `getScript` cached?

Comment: @DotNETNinja I edited my answer, is this what you are searching for? Try to look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ if you need to know more, or comment if you cant figure it out.

Comment: good code snippet, thank you! I'll wait a little for any another solution and accept yours if the will not